# Catch all module exceptions to not crash the main app

Tags: android, android-library

I'm working on a **library module** (using gradle and proguard) on Android that will be integrated in other application.

Is there a solution to **catch all exceptions thrown** by a library so if the library have some NPE or exception in other threads (like an OMX exception), the main app will not crash.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: I haven't digged much about it. the Nitesh answer need more attention and we can maybe rethrow the exception afterward if it was not related to the library itself. 
I've also use the Exception handling on EventBus that did work well.

Comment: okay, I try to implement  Exception handling + EventBus. Maybe you have example? It will be great!

Comment: You can subscribe for an event on a specific Thread (= not the main one, you cannot control it) http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/delivery-threads-threadmode/
  
And receive the throwed exception from EventBus:    
```
    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onSubscriberExceptionEvent(SubscriberExceptionEvent event) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29) but if you got uncaught exception then the flow of your app is already interrupted and recovery is usually very hard / impossible. Perhaps the only useful case to catch all the uncaught exceptions is to report it back to developer so you can nail the bug and fix. But if that's your goal, then I'd rather use existing solutions like Crittercism or so.

Answer (score -1):

You can look for any uncaught exception in your liberary project

```
private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler _unCaughtExceptionHandler = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {

       //Put a check if it is thrown by your liberary then deal with it.

    }
};

 Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(_unCaughtExceptionHandler);
```

Comment: but that would caught any app exception that are not catch right ?

Comment: yup it will catch all the exceptions that are not handled by you using try catch.